# CruiseControl.NET Server is hanging at the 'Pending' activity status when it is started as an Automatic service

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

My CruiseControl.NET Server is hanging at the `Pending` activity status when a force build is triggered through CCTray or via the CCNet web dashboard. I seem to notice that it is doing this when the CC service is set to automatic startup type in the service manager.

It proceeds as normal when I run it as a console service using `ccnet.exe` and trigger the force build. I can't see any error on the console to help me figure out why it is not working when it is run as a normal service.

It was originally set to the automatic startup type service and seems to be working fine till a couple of days ago. I'm not sure what changed but how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

My only guess is when you run it as ccnet.exe it is running under your account, but when started from service manager it is running under a service account like Network Service and thus having trouble accessing something.

Try configuring the windows service to use Local Service or Local System account, or even just as a test, enter your own account credentials.

Whatever account you run the service under, will not only need file access rights, but probably also need permission to your source control system.

Comment: I'm using the Administrator account, and it's been configured to run as the Administrator account under the service manager. It was originally this way and working as well. Still not sure why it is hung at the pending status. I'll give the Local Service and Local System account a try and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the queue property of the projects . I'm quoting the project configuration block section's queue property documentation.

> "The priority of this project within the integration queue. If
>   multiple projects have pending requests in the specified queue then
>   these requests will be executed according to their priority. Lower
>   priority numbers indicate that integration requests for this project
>   will execute before other projects in the same queue, however projects
>   with priority 0 are always executed after projects with non-zero
>   priorities in the same queue."

More information can be found at http://cruisecontrolnet.org/ docs